# How to run executable jar file with multiple external libraries in linux

Tags: java, linux, shell

I've been trying to run an executable jar but somehow it returns an error that my class is not existing. I tried to search the web on different ways to run it and I have tried the following so far:

```
java -cp Unirest.jar:lib/*
java -cp Unirest.jar:/home/appstemp/phuzca/lib/
java -cp Unirest.jar;/home/appstemp/phuzca/lib/*; MainMethod
javac -cp '.:/home/appstemp/phuzca/lib/*.jar' Unirest.jar
javac -cp '.:/home/appstemp/phuzca/lib/*.jar' Unirest
java -cp "Unirest.jar;lib/*" com.unirest.request.MainMethod.java
java -cp "Unirest.jar;lib/*" com.unirest.request.MainMethod
java -cp .:lib/* com.unirest.request.MainMethod
java -classpath lib/*:. com.unirest.request.MainMethod
java -cp "/lib/*:" Unirest.jar
java -cp "/home/appstemp/phuzca/lib/*:" Unirest.jar
java -classpath "/home/appstemp/phuzca/lib/*:." com.unirest.request.MainMethod
java -cp "Unirest.jar;lib/*" com.unirest.request.MainMethod
```

But none of them worked. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `java -jar Unirest.jar` Have you tried this.?

Comment: yes I did. if I do that, I won't be able to call the external libraries of my jar

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this executable jar and multiple external library.? Can you explain more so that we can help?

Comment: you can export the external libraries to the $CLASSPATH and just call the executable jar as  java -cp mainclassname

Comment: You last attempt was the closest.  Always use `:` as a path entry separator, in operating systems other than Windows.  Try `java -cp "Unirest.jar:lib/*" com.unirest.request.MainMethod`.

Comment: @jack jav - what I'm running is a unirest request so I have a couple of jar files that are required so that my jar would run. I have checkd the web for answers and a guy proposed that I should name each library one by one. Well I can't name them all one by one right?

Comment: @BEN SEBASTIAN - could you kindly provide more info on that please?

Comment: @VGR - thanks man. that worked

Comment: I think your able to set the external libraries files location into the class path ,so once you set the classpath , after trying to execute  the jar it will check the system classpath and refer the external libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting the answer that was given to me, so everyone can see. Thanks @VGR:

```
java -cp "Unirest.jar:lib/*" com.unirest.request.MainMethod
```

Used colon(:) instead of semicolon(;)